# How To Send A Discord.JS Startup Message To All Servers

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanted to inquire on something I’ve been trying to do recently. I have a Discord.JS bot, and it’s pretty public (130+ servers), and I want it to send a message to any channel in every single server it’s in, when the bot starts up, the purpose is to create a “New Update” notification in one of the channels.

Comment: What's the question? This isn't a code writing service

Comment: Even if you had an actual code here, I would highly recommend for you to call this idea off immediately due to your client being rate limited immediately after startup, and yourself potentially banned from API usage by implementing this feature due to abuse.

Answer (score 0):

## Please do not plan on doing this, as this will get you rate limited really quickly.

This is kind of possible. There is a problem, there is no default guild channel, so you cannot get their "main" channel just by their guild object. If you would want to do that you, would need them to select their channel and store that ID somewhere.

This is a simple solution, where you loop through every guild of your Discord client, and send some channel a message. You don't know what channel with this solution specifically, but you will send some channel a message if it is not a voice channel.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
require("dotenv").config();

// Creating our Client
const client = new Discord.Client();

// Event listener: when the bot is ready
client.on("ready", () => {
  // Looping through every guild the bot is in
    client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild) => {
    // Getting one of their channels
        let channel = guild.channels.cache.array()[2];
    // Sending the channel a message
        channel.send("Hey");
    });
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Please do not follow this method. Not only will it get you rate limited, but there is an extremely high chance of you being temporarily (or in some cases permanently) banned from API usage.